# How should outliers be dealt with in latent growth curve/GMM modeling?

Tags: outliers, latent-class, growth-model

When doing analysis of growth trajectories you often find natural outliers. Often these are not because of any "errors" in the dataset, they are simply there because certain cases grew at an explosive rate compared to the majority of the cases in the dataset. A case in point is open source repositories where most seem to exhibit moderate growth, whereas some (Linux, Twitter Bootstrap, etc.) exhibits very high growth rates.

This can lead to difficulties when estimating latent growth curve models and growth mixture models. For example, in the latter case it is often difficult to perform statistical tests (such as the LRT significance test for K and K-1 class models) when outliers are present, since they tend to be placed in a class of their own with a very small class membership (low N) therefore preventing reliable significance testing. Some packages, such as Mplus even refuse to calculate the LRT statistic if a class has fewer than 5% of total N in a single class.

**What statistical tests or rules of thumb can be used as a basis for excluding outliers in latent growth curve/GMM analysis?**

**Are there any special considerations for growth mixture modeling?**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance and http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/mahalanobis.html are good starts for the Mahalanobis distance, which is a good measure for multivariate outliers. Of course you can still check for univariate outliers!